# Using SUM in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an error while running this query. 
Error : ORA-00937 not a single-group group function.

My code is

```
SELECT 
    SUM(UL.ACTION_CODE*UL.MASS_NET) AS WINDER_NET , 
    SUM(U.MASS_SCALED) AS SCALED_NET,
    (
        SELECT SUM(JRL.MASS_CALCULATED) 
        FROM JUMBOREELLOG JRL 
        WHERE 
            JRL.DATE_TRANSACTION >= to_date('08/01/2020 06:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
            AND JRL.DATE_TRANSACTION < to_date('09/01/2020 06:01' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
            AND JRL.JUMBO_TRANSACTION_TYPE IN('TU','HY') 
            AND JRL.STATION_CODE = 'PM1P'
    ) AS JUMBO_TOTAL
FROM UNIT U
INNER JOIN  UNITLOG UL ON U.UNIT_ID = UL.UNIT_ID
WHERE 
    UL.DATE_TRANSACTION >= to_date('08/01/2020 06:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
    AND UL.DATE_TRANSACTION < to_date('09/01/2020 06:01' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
```

Expected Output is three columns Winder_Net, Scaled_Net and Jumbo_Total with some integer values. If someone please guide me how to create a table here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. It is not clear why you do not include `Group by`; however, your query would be correct in other DBMS such as SQL Server or MySQL. I suggest to rewrite it using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(UL.ACTION_CODE*UL.MASS_NET) AS WINDER_NET , 
        SUM(U.MASS_SCALED) AS SCALED_NET,
    FROM UNIT U
    INNER JOIN  UNITLOG UL ON U.UNIT_ID = UL.UNIT_ID
    WHERE 
        UL.DATE_TRANSACTION >= to_date('08/01/2020 06:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
        AND UL.DATE_TRANSACTION < to_date('09/01/2020 06:01' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
) 
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(JRL.MASS_CALCULATED) JUMBO_TOTAL
    FROM JUMBOREELLOG JRL 
    WHERE 
        JRL.DATE_TRANSACTION >= to_date('08/01/2020 06:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
        AND JRL.DATE_TRANSACTION < to_date('09/01/2020 06:01' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
        AND JRL.JUMBO_TRANSACTION_TYPE IN('TU','HY') 
        AND JRL.STATION_CODE = 'PM1P'
)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=deb971ae4aa08f70cdcd62907a60f94f) you can find an example simulating your problem and [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9cd742d155042f46740e80f3068ea9a3) you can find a solution using the `CROSS JOIN`.